# Buttons functionality in Ubuntu on a Macbook pro

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, macbook-pro, ubuntu-10.10

I have installed Ubuntu (10.10) on a Macbook pro (6,2).

Does anyone know how to get the following buttons functionality:
- Delete (fn+backspace doesn't work)
- Home
- End

The keyboard does not have a delete button - just backspace.
Delete is the most missed one :(

Update:
I don't know what I did but it works now.
I king of did almost all that is written [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro6-2/Maverick).
One of them probably helped.

Comment: If you found an answer, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the keyboard variant to a Mac keyboard? It's in System > Preferences > Keyboard > Layouts, you can add new layouts there. Select your layout and the Mac variant.

Comment: Yes, I did but it did not help. What helped is what I wrote below